# Select element closes immediately when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, hide

I've got several select elements like this in my page

```
<div class="question_input_type_selector selector_div hide">
    <select class="custom-dropdown input_type_selector">
       <option value="multiple_choice" default="" selected="">Escolha Múltipla</option>
       <option value="scale_input">Escala</option>
       <option value="grid_input">Grelha de escolha múltipla</option>
       <option value="text">Texto</option>
       <option value="checkboxes">Caixas de verificação</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

It works correctly if I don't do anything to it. But when I hide the div with `.hide()` and then show it again with `.show()`, all the select elements stop working properly. Every time I click on one of them, it opens and closes immediately and it is impossible to select an option. The only way to keep it opened is by clicking it, dragging the mouse somewhere else while holding the button down and only then releasing it.

I have tried everything and Googled everything I could for several days and can't find a solution.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried this on multiple browsers? (Chrome, IE, Firefox, etc.)

Comment: show the `show/hide` code.

Comment: can u used .toggle()

Comment: It does not work on Chrome, Firefox and Chrome for android.

The show/hide code is just:
$('.question_div').find('.hide').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).find('.hint').val()) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

Comment: What is `.hint`? Just try `$('.question_div').find('.hide').click(function(){ $(this).fadeToggle(); });`

Comment: If an element has a child with the class ".hint" and the child has some value attached it won't hide. I tried .fadeToggle() and when I clicked the select element it opened and then disappeared slowly.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the cause for this problem.

Everytime I clicked inside the div where the select is, I called a function that hides all the divs and shows only the clicked div. So, I couldn't see the div disappearing and appearing, because the two events were simultaneous, but the fact that the div disappeared right after the select open caused the select element to close immediately.

The solution was adding a condition and calling the function to hide all divs only if the clicked div was not already focused.